# Tracking a biased coin flip experiment - Binomial distribution in python

Tags: python, probability, probability-distribution

There is a 15% chance of getting heads. 85% chance of getting tails. I want to see how many coin flips it will take me to get a heads.

Everytime I flip a coin, I want to put that number in an empty list stating the number of tries it took me to flip the coin.

I want to flip the coin a total of 100 times

```
def coin_flips(n):
   for i in range(n): #for i in the number of coin flips
       #will continue until we break
       empty_list: []
       while True:
           #flip coin
           flipped_coins = np.random.choice(['tails', 'heads'], p = [0.85, 0.15])
          #add count number of flipped cons
           n += 1
           #if coin lands on heads
           if flipped_coins == 'heads':
               #add integer to empty list
               empty_list += n
       #if the coin lands on tails
       else:
           #flip the coin again until it lands on heads
               open_box = np.random.choice(['empty', 'elixir'], p = [0.85, 0.15])
               #add the count of coins flipped
               n += 1

       return empty_list
n = 10_000
```

Comment: What are the results you're getting?

Comment: You're looking actually at Negative binomial distribution, I believe - number of successes before first failure, NB(1, 0.85)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number of times you flipped the coin until you got a heads

```py
def flip_coins(n, head_prob):
    flips = 0
    heads = False
    while not heads:
        flips += 1
        flipped_coins = np.random.choice(['tails','heads'], p=[1-head_prod, head_prob])
        heads = flipped_coins == 'heads'
    return flips
```

If you then wanted a list of the amounts it took:

```py
total_flips = [flip_coins(100, .15) for n in range(10_000)]
```